# Sort gcloud firestore operations by start time descending

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I am trying to get the status of the latest firestore export via Gcloud CLI.

However, if I execute

```
gcloud firestore operations list --limit=5 --sort-by="~metadata.startTime"
```

the results are not sorted by the start time in descending order.
If I add `--format="value(metadata.startTime)"`, I get the correct output

```
2023-01-17T00:05:13.818312Z
2023-01-17T15:30:19.362908Z
2023-01-18T08:11:18.433556Z
2023-01-19T00:05:01.440255Z
2023-01-20T00:05:04.135387Z
```

How can I achieve the results being sorted by the startTime in descending order?

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it seems you are using the `--sort-by` flag incorrectly it should be used with `[ ]` as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/firestore/operations/list#--sort-by).

The final command would be:

```
gcloud firestore operations list --limit=5 --sort-by=[~metadata.startTime] --format="value(metadata.startTime)"
```

This will list the last 5 operations and sort them by start time in descending order.

But when I tried with above command also it seems the issue is still there.I have raised this [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/266196342) at with google.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and raising the issue with Google. Oddly enough, even without the `[ ]`, the sorting works as expected on the operation name. But anything containing the timestamp seems to ignore that.

Comment: @sg.sysel yes I have also tried at my end It should have given a syntax error for that instead of accepting as it is.